# TKinter: Listbox population misunderstanding. Help appreciated

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am developing a very crude window to broaden my understanding of certain TKinter widgets like comboboxes and scales.

The current widget I am working on is a simple Listbox featuring a list of pages to visit.
I have gotten stuck trying to understand the use of *Stringvar* to populate the listbox.

I am basing the code off of this snippet from TKDocs:

```
choices = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
choicesvar = StringVar(value=choices)
```

This is my code:

```
other_frames = ['Cameras', 'Tasks', 'Maintainance', 'Clock', 'Assistance', 'Tools']
StringVar = " "
O_F_var = StringVar(value=other_frames)
```

I am getting errors on this step and only this step, so I am obviously *misunderstanding* how to use a *stringvar* and/or what value to give a *stringvar*.

---

I read on the TKDocs website that just like *Entry*, the *Listbox* also uses *StringVar*.
To try and understand, I visited the explanation for the *Entry* widget. And in the code snippet, the value for *StringVar* was a *nonetype*.

TKDocs code snippet:

```
username = StringVar()
name = ttk.Entry(parent, textvariable=username)
```

I tried using a *Nonetype value for my StringVar* and I **expected** to have the Listbox become populated by the List values since I had "used a StringVar as an intermediary." like the TKDocs tutorial said.

I **instead** recieved the error:

**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

I then tried to figure out why things were not lining up, sadly to no avail.

An explanation and/or resource to help me understand would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringVar` is a class in tkinter. You can't just use `StringVar = " "` and expect that to work. You need to create an instance of the `StringVar` class.

In this case, however, you're wanting to use a variable for a `Listbox`, and a listbox works on lists rather than strings. If you use a list as a value for a `StringVar`, tkinter will convert the list to a string and destroy the fact that it represents a list.

Instead, when using the variable with a `Listbox` you can use the `Variable` class, which will preserve the base type of the data.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

choices = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.Variable(value=choices)

lb = tk.Listbox(root, listvariable=var)
lb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]